# Image Color and Saturation

Tags: saturation

I am having Nikon D7000. I have couple of questions about colors in my images.

1. How can I add Color Saturation?
2. In most of my images, I feel colors are not so vibrant. How to make colors more vibrant?

Comment: See: http://photo.stackexchange.com/a/20640/4892

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do pros manage to make the color green so bright in their nature photographs?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20636/how-do-pros-manage-to-make-the-color-green-so-bright-in-their-nature-photographs)

Comment: I think this question should stay. I'm a Canon guy but I know I can adjust saturation and others things from the Canon menu. Presumably Nikon does that also. JPG only of course.

Answer (score 5):

The *right* answer is "check your user manual". Your camera has a lot of potential, and learning to navigate its various options will help you take better photos.

Another "right" answer is to shoot in RAW mode and adjust things like color saturation as necessary for each photo using a good photo editing program (Lightroom, Aperture, etc.). That may be more effort than you're up for, though.

Most DSLR's, yours included, have a number of preset configurations that let you choose a photo style. This is a quick and easy way for you to say "I want brighter, more saturated colors!" without much trouble. You give up a lot of control with these settings, but it sounds like you might be okay with that.

You may find this helpful: [Nikon D7000 Color Settings: What, Where, When, and Why](http://daltonphoto.com/blog/?p=793)

In brief, use the "Shooting Menu" to select "Set Picture Control". Choose the "Vivid" setting for increased color saturation.